# Column replacement with awk, with retaining the format

Tags: replace, awk, format

This is file `a.pdb`:

```
ATOM      1  N   ARG     1       0.000   0.000   0.000  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM      2  H1  ARG     1       0.000   0.000   0.000  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM      3  H2  ARG     1       0.000   0.000   0.000  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM      4  H3  ARG     1       0.000   0.000   0.000  1.00  0.00           H
```

And this is file `a.xyz`:

```
16.388 -5.760 -23.332
17.226 -5.608 -23.768
15.760 -5.238 -23.831
17.921 -5.926 -26.697
```

I want to replace 6,7 and 8th column of `a.pdb` with `a.xyz` columns.  Once replaced, I need to maintain tabs/space/columns of `a.pdb`.

I have tried:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {fld1[NR]=$1; fld2[NR]=$2; fld3[NR]=$3; next} {$6=fld1[FNR]; $7=fld2[FNR]; $8=fld3[FNR]}1' a.xyz a.pdb
```

But it doesn't keep the format.

Comment: What's the replacement algorithm? First line of one file with content of first line of the other one?

Comment: The line numbers are matching. @fedorqui

Comment: Well I guess `a.pdb` is tab separated, while `a.xyz` is space separated. What if you make both of them tab sep?

Comment: I tried that with cat a.xyz | column -t option, but after awk replacement a.pdb looses its format. It doesn't keep the column number alignment.

Comment: make your FS and OFS explict with `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` ? Good luck.

Comment: Try setting `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}`, but I insist that `a.xyz` should be tab separated to have it working. Otherwise, with this `FS` and `OFS` setting the fetching part will break.

Answer (score 11):

This is exactly what the 4th arg for split() in GNU awk was invented to facilitate:

```
gawk '
NR==FNR { pdb[NR]=$0; next }
{
    split(pdb[FNR],flds,FS,seps)
    flds[6]=$1
    flds[7]=$2
    flds[8]=$3
    for (i=1;i in flds;i++)
        printf "%s%s", flds[i], seps[i]
    print ""
}
' a.pdb a.xyz

ATOM      1  N   ARG     1       16.388   -5.760   -23.332  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM      2  H1  ARG     1       17.226   -5.608   -23.768  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM      3  H2  ARG     1       15.760   -5.238   -23.831  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM      4  H3  ARG     1       17.921   -5.926   -26.697  1.00  0.00           H
```

Comment: Nicely done. I would like to leverage my upvote for one question `:)`. In the `for loop` you chose to use `i in flds` instead of capturing `split` function return value and doing `i<=n`. Is there an advantage of doing this?

Comment: Not a big deal either way, it's just one less global variable that you don't need to worry about populating and maybe clashing with a variable of the same name elsewhere in the script. Obviously not a problem in a script this small. Note that this approach only works when there's no holes in the array indices.

Comment: Ok got it! Thanks for the explanation. +1 duly given! BTW, We badly need an `awk` cookbook on everyone's desk! *wink wink*

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about it. Something like Chris Johnson's "Bash Scripting Recipes" but for awk. Someday...

Comment: +1 for the nice feature with gawk, Ed. But the decimal points are not in the 35, 43 and 51st columns.

Comment: Nice! But note that `seps[0]` can contain empty space in the beginning of the line. (You do not print that space.)..

Comment: @Scrutinizer - that isn't mentioned in the question and would conflict with the stated requirement to retain spacing as-is.

Comment: @HåkonHægland - correct, the OPs posted input lines don't start with spaces so there was no point printing a null string at the front but there is a null string at the end too, it was just a choice to print `flds[i], seps[i]` instead of `seps[i-1], flds[i]` or similar.

Answer (score 3):

Not a general solution, but this might work with in this particular case:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{for(i=6; i<=8; i++) A[FNR,i]=$(i-5); next} {for(i=6; i<=8; i++) sub($i,A[FNR,i])}1' file2 file1
```

or

```
awk '{for(i=6; i<=8; i++) if(NR==FNR) A[FNR,i]=$(i-5); else sub($i,A[FNR,i])} NR>FNR' file2 file1
```

There is a bit of a shift, though. We would need to know the fields widths to prevent this.

--
Or perhaps with substrings:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[FNR]=$0; next} {print substr($0,1,p) FS A[FNR] substr($0,p+length(A[FNR]))}' p=33 file2 file1
```

-- changing it in the OP's original solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {fld1[NR]=$1; fld2[NR]=$2; fld3[NR]=$3; next} {sub($6,fld1[FNR]); sub($7,fld2[FNR]); sub($8,fld3[FNR])}1' file file1
```

with the same restrictions as the first 2 suggestions.

So 1, 2, and 4 use `sub` to replace, which is not a water proof solution, since earlier fields might interfere and it uses regex rather than strings (and so the regex dot happens to match the actual dot), but with this particular input, it might pan out..

Probably nr. 3 would be a more fool-proof method..

--edit--
I think this would work with the given input:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[FNR]=$1 "  " $2 " " $3; next} {print substr($0,1,p) A[FNR] substr($0,p+length(A[FNR]))}' p=32  file2 file1
```

but I think something like `printf` or `sprint` formatting would be required to make it fool-proof.
So, perhaps something like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[FNR]=sprintf("%7.3f %7.3f %8.4f", $1, $2, $3); next} {print substr($0,1,p) A[FNR] substr($0,p+length(A[FNR]))}' p=31 file2 file1
```

or not on one line:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {
    A[FNR]=sprintf("%7.3f %7.3f %8.4f", $1, $2, $3)
    next
  }
  {
    print substr($0,1,p) A[FNR] substr($0,p+length(A[FNR]))
  }
' p=31 file2 file1
```

Comment: Note the OPs syntax is fine, he is only asking about keeping the format.

Comment: @fedorqui, good point, I added an adaptation to the other suggestions.

Comment: It works except a small shift in 6-8th column. The 6-8th column in a.pdb are left alligned. The decimal point should appear in 35, 43 and 51st columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
paste -d' '  test4 test5 |awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$12,$13,$14,$9,$10,$11}'
```