# Replacement of a column and keeping the same format

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file looks like this

```
ATOM      1  N   GLN     1      68.560  76.330  53.810  1.00  0.00            
ATOM      2  H1  GLN     1      68.030  75.660  54.340  1.00  0.00            
ATOM      3  H2  GLN     1      67.890  76.960  53.390  1.00  0.00            
ATOM      4  H3  GLN     1      69.090  76.880  54.480  1.00  0.00            
ATOM      5  CA  GLN     1      69.370  75.700  52.760  1.00  0.00            
ATOM      6  HA  GLN     1      70.400  76.070  52.820  1.00  0.00            
ATOM      7  CB  GLN     1      69.490  74.180  52.870  1.00  0.00            
ATOM      8  HB2 GLN     1      69.650  73.790  53.880  1.00  0.00            
ATOM      9  HB3 GLN     1      68.520  73.740  52.650  1.00  0.00            
ATOM     10  CG  GLN     1      70.560  73.570  51.970  1.00  0.00
```

I want to substitute column 9 with 0.00 and I used awk like following

```
awk '{if($9 == "1.00") $9 = "0.00"; print}' test.pdb >mod_test.pdb
```

But that completely messes up the format. Any suggestions to retain the format while substitution?

This is kind of similar post of [column replacement with awk, with retaining the format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203066/column-replacement-with-awk-with-retaining-the-format) but I didn't get the `split()` argument mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might be easier with `sed`, to replace the penultimate field

```
$ sed -E 's/(\s)1.00(\s[^\s]+)$/\10.00\2/' file
```

you can replace `[^\s]` with `\S` if your `sed` supports it.

Comment: Only thing is that it takes advantage of field position being last-1 instead of using 9th field

Comment: Unfortunately in sed `[^\s]` means `any character other than s` since you can't put the `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]` inside a bracket expression and then try to negate it, nor is `\S` for `[^[:space:]]` supported.. In sed just use the POSIX character class names to avoid the many "gotchas".

Answer (score 2):

You may pipe your `awk` command to `column -t`:

```
awk '$9 == "1.00" {$9 = "0.00"} 1' file | column -t
```

```
ATOM  1   N    GLN  1  68.560  76.330  53.810  0.00  0.00
ATOM  2   H1   GLN  1  68.030  75.660  54.340  0.00  0.00
ATOM  3   H2   GLN  1  67.890  76.960  53.390  0.00  0.00
ATOM  4   H3   GLN  1  69.090  76.880  54.480  0.00  0.00
ATOM  5   CA   GLN  1  69.370  75.700  52.760  0.00  0.00
ATOM  6   HA   GLN  1  70.400  76.070  52.820  0.00  0.00
ATOM  7   CB   GLN  1  69.490  74.180  52.870  0.00  0.00
ATOM  8   HB2  GLN  1  69.650  73.790  53.880  0.00  0.00
ATOM  9   HB3  GLN  1  68.520  73.740  52.650  0.00  0.00
ATOM  10  CG   GLN  1  70.560  73.570  51.970  0.00  0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

The generic way to set the 9th field using any sed that has a `-E` arg for EREs (e.g. GNU sed):

```
$ sed -E 's/(([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){8})[^[:space:]]+/\10.00/' file
ATOM      1  N   GLN     1      68.560  76.330  53.810  0.00  0.00
ATOM      2  H1  GLN     1      68.030  75.660  54.340  0.00  0.00
ATOM      3  H2  GLN     1      67.890  76.960  53.390  0.00  0.00
ATOM      4  H3  GLN     1      69.090  76.880  54.480  0.00  0.00
ATOM      5  CA  GLN     1      69.370  75.700  52.760  0.00  0.00
ATOM      6  HA  GLN     1      70.400  76.070  52.820  0.00  0.00
ATOM      7  CB  GLN     1      69.490  74.180  52.870  0.00  0.00
ATOM      8  HB2 GLN     1      69.650  73.790  53.880  0.00  0.00
ATOM      9  HB3 GLN     1      68.520  73.740  52.650  0.00  0.00
ATOM     10  CG  GLN     1      70.560  73.570  51.970  0.00  0.00
```

The generic way to set the 9th field using GNU awk for the 4th arg to split():

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    split($0,flds,FS,seps)
    flds[9] = "0.00"
    out = seps[0]
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        out = out flds[i] seps[i]
    }
    print out
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
ATOM      1  N   GLN     1      68.560  76.330  53.810  0.00  0.00
ATOM      2  H1  GLN     1      68.030  75.660  54.340  0.00  0.00
ATOM      3  H2  GLN     1      67.890  76.960  53.390  0.00  0.00
ATOM      4  H3  GLN     1      69.090  76.880  54.480  0.00  0.00
ATOM      5  CA  GLN     1      69.370  75.700  52.760  0.00  0.00
ATOM      6  HA  GLN     1      70.400  76.070  52.820  0.00  0.00
ATOM      7  CB  GLN     1      69.490  74.180  52.870  0.00  0.00
ATOM      8  HB2 GLN     1      69.650  73.790  53.880  0.00  0.00
ATOM      9  HB3 GLN     1      68.520  73.740  52.650  0.00  0.00
ATOM     10  CG  GLN     1      70.560  73.570  51.970  0.00  0.00
```

Comment: Both of these commands are pretty good and would maintain exact same spacing as in input