# Changing string in a specific column for a range of lines without losing spaces/format

Tags: awk, curly-braces

I have a file with many lines, but I am hoping to change a string `X` in my fifth column for the first 4635 lines into another string `A`, without losing the original tabs/spacings between the columns.

I am hoping to change (for a certain range of lines)

```
ATOM   2732  HN  SER X 176     181.410 174.270 311.410  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2733  CA  SER X 176     180.170 172.920 310.330  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2734  HA  SER X 176     179.860 171.950 310.720  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2735  CB  SER X 176     179.010 173.910 310.790  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2736  HB1 SER X 176     178.020 173.710 310.340  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2737  HB2 SER X 176     178.910 173.930 311.900  0.00  0.00
```

into

```
ATOM   2732  HN  SER A 176     181.410 174.270 311.410  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2733  CA  SER A 176     180.170 172.920 310.330  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2734  HA  SER A 176     179.860 171.950 310.720  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2735  CB  SER A 176     179.010 173.910 310.790  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2736  HB1 SER A 176     178.020 173.710 310.340  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2737  HB2 SER A 176     178.910 173.930 311.900  0.00  0.00
```

I came up with the following code,

```
awk '{if (NR>=1&&NR<=4635) split($0, a, FS, seps); a[5]="A"; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s%s", a[i], seps[i]); print ""}' dat > tmp
```

but it seems that all lines in the file now have `A` in the fifth column, instead of lines 1-4635. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [column replacement with awk, with retaining the format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203066/column-replacement-with-awk-with-retaining-the-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add curly brackets/braces and an `else` branch:

```
awk '{if (NR>=1&&NR<=4635) {split($0, a, FS, seps); a[5]="A"; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s%s", a[i], seps[i]); print ""} else {print}}' dat > tmp
```

Without curly brackets/braces `if`'s body only contains a `split` command.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for the 4th arg to split().

Comment: Also you may remove `NR>=1` as this is a UUONR!

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `\s/\S` shorthand:

```
$ awk 'NR<4636{match($0,/((\S+\s+){4}).(.*)/,a); $0=a[1] "A" a[3]} 1' file
ATOM   2732  HN  SER A 176     181.410 174.270 311.410  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2733  CA  SER A 176     180.170 172.920 310.330  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2734  HA  SER A 176     179.860 171.950 310.720  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2735  CB  SER A 176     179.010 173.910 310.790  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2736  HB1 SER A 176     178.020 173.710 310.340  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2737  HB2 SER A 176     178.910 173.930 311.900  0.00  0.00
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk 'NR<4636{match($0,/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){4}./); $0=substr($0,1,RLENGTH-1) "A" substr($0,RLENGTH+1)} 1' file
ATOM   2732  HN  SER A 176     181.410 174.270 311.410  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2733  CA  SER A 176     180.170 172.920 310.330  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2734  HA  SER A 176     179.860 171.950 310.720  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2735  CB  SER A 176     179.010 173.910 310.790  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2736  HB1 SER A 176     178.020 173.710 310.340  0.00  0.00
ATOM   2737  HB2 SER A 176     178.910 173.930 311.900  0.00  0.00
```

Answer (score 3):

If your input is fixed width fields like shown in the sample, then you can use `FIELDWIDTHS` with `GNU awk`:

```sh
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='21 1 *' -v OFS= 'NR<=4635{$2="A"} 1'
```

Here, first field is made up of `21` characters, second field is `1` character and rest is third field. You can then change the second field only for required lines.

If input is not fixed width, then, you can use `sed` or `perl`:

```sh
# GNU sed
sed -E '1,4635 s/^((\S+\s+){4})\S+/\1A/'

# if \s and \S isn't supported
sed -E '1,4635 s/^(([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){4})[^[:space:]]+/\1A/'

perl -pe 's/^(\S+\s+){4}\K\S+/A/ if $.<=4635'
```

Comment: Nice use of FIELDWIDTHS plus null OFS!