# Modify values of one column based on values of another column on a line-by-line basis

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, multiple-columns, edit

I'm looking to use bash/awk/sed in order to modify a document.

The document contains multiple columns. Column 5 currently has the value "A" at every row. Column six is composed of increasing numbers. I'm attempting a script that goes through the document line by line, checks the value of Column 6, if the value is greater than a certain integer (specifically 275) the value of Column 5 in that same line is changed to "B".

```
while IFS="" read -r line ; do
 awk 'BEGIN {FS = " "}'
 Num=$(awk '{print $6}' original.txt)
 if [ $Num > 275 ] ; then
  awk '{ gsub("A","B",$5) }'
 fi
done < original.txt >> edited.txt
```

For the above, I've tried setting the residueNum variable both inside and outside of the while loop.

I've also tried using a for loop and cat:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = " "}' original.txt
Num=$(awk '{print $6}' heterodimer_P49913/unrelaxed_model_1.pdb)
integer=275

for data in $Num ; do
  if [ $data > $integer ] ; then
   ##Change value in other column to "B" for all lines containing column 6 values greater than "integer"
  fi
done
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not simply `awk '$6>275{ $5="B" }1' original.txt >edited.txt` ?

Comment: please update the question with a sample of rows from the source file, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output, making sure all outputs correspond to the provided sample input

Comment: Awk never needs lines fed to it, it automatically processes a file line-by-line as default. Likewise, white space never needs to be set at the field separator, that is the default. @M.NejatAydin 's comment above is the correct procedure for your needs. The format is awk 'condition {action if condition met}. Incidentally, the 1 in that answer is a shorthand block telling awk to output the line - now modified by the explicit action block preceding it (if the condition was met) or unchanged if the condition was not met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU `AWK` does not need external while loop (there is implicit loop), if you need further explanation read [`awk` info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info). Let `file.txt` content be

```
1 2 3 4 A 100
1 2 3 4 A 275
1 2 3 4 A 300
```

and task to be

> checks the value of Column 6, if the value is greater than a certain
> integer (specifically 275) the value of Column 5 in that same line is
> changed to "B".

then it might be done using GNU `AWK` following way

```
awk '$6>275{$5="B"}{print}' file.txt
```

which gives output

```
1 2 3 4 A 100
1 2 3 4 A 275
1 2 3 4 B 300
```

Explanation: action set value of 5th field (`$5`) to B is applied conditionally to rows where value of 6th field is greater than 275. Action to `print` is applied unconditionally to all lines. Observe that change if applied is done before `print`ing.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Thank you for the easy solution. However, I also need to preserve original white space. I've tried implementing the split() command as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203066/column-replacement-with-awk-with-retaining-the-format , but can't wrap my head around how to use it for this case.